# Meta programming in Django get_foo_display, foo_set and others, how does it work?

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming

I have a user model with a profile UserProfile.
Somehow my user can have several type of books: TA, TB, TC, TD.
Those choices are defined in a choices tuple in my model (standard way).

From my template I would like to be able to call

```
{{ user.get_profile.has_book_type_TA }}
```

and returns True/False.

TA is the dynamic part, it could be rewritten as:

**has_book_type_[type_name]**

How can I write this kind of method in my model ?

```
def has_book_type_(self, type_name):
    ...
```

But how to make it callable as get_profile.has_book_type_TA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `__init__` method for your model, walk through the different types of books and create properties:

```
for book_type in BOOK_TYPES:
  setattr(self, 'has_book_type_%s' % book_type, self.has_book_type_(book_type))
```

Then in your templates, checking `user.get_profile.has_book_type_TA` should work.